# VBA to find the greatest and lowest value but getting run time error

Tags: vba, worksheet-function

I am using the max and min function in VBA to find the greatest and lowest value but I am getting an error

```
Greatest_Percent = WorksheetFunction.Max(ws.Range("L2:L"))
Lowest_Percent = WorksheetFunction.Min(ws.Range("L2:L"))
```

Run Time Error
Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed

Answer (score 0):

This is because the range is being defined wrongfully as `L2:L`; eg. `L2:L101` would rather work.
If you want the range to be selected dynamically , then it would still be exactly the same syntax:

```
Dim lastrow As Integer
lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row   

Range("L2:L" & lastrow)
```